# How to calculate the energy needed to ionize air at a specific temperature?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

I have not found any information relating to using electicity to ionize air with temperature, but I am sure that there should be some information available. 
I am thinking of the nozzle of modern jet engine (about 2000℃)considering I don't have any sophisticated equipment.

Is there any way to measure or even calculate the energy(Joule) needed to maintain ionization of air at high temperature(2000℃)?

Comment: For clarity, how are you ionizing the air (thermal, electrical, chemical...) and  how ionized (fraction) do you need it?

Comment: Well air is made up of a number of types of atoms/ molecules.  The ionization potential for nitrogen is about 14.5 eV (according to this,http://environmentalchemistry.com/yogi/periodic/1stionization.html.)  Temperature will only have a small effect, unless it get's very hot... kT is several eV.  (kT is 25 meV, 0.025 eV at 300K.)

Comment: Followup question: Are you interested in energy specifically (Joules) or are you looking for the voltage required to cause/sustain ionization. These are different problems with different answers.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold And what about the creation of the $N_2^+$ ions? Maybe it is easier as to produce nascens $N_2$ first, and then ionize it.

Answer (score 1):

As Herold has stated Nitrogen has a rather high ionization potential.  However the voltage needed to ionize air depends on alot of other factors:
density 
altitude
humidity
mean temperature
presence of dust
etc